# Internal energy change during phase change

Tags: thermodynamics

> Ice at $\mathrm{0\ ^\circ C}$ is converted to water at $\mathrm{0\ ^\circ C}$. If $\Delta H$ for the transition of ice to water is $\mathrm{1440~cal}$, calculate the change in internal energy.

Since internal energy $\Delta U=nC_V\Delta T$ and $\Delta T=0$, shouldn't $\Delta U=0$?

But if I use $ 
\Delta H=\Delta U +\Delta nRT$, I get $\Delta U=\Delta H\neq 0$.

Comment: The equation you wrote for $\Delta H$ applies only to an ideal gas (assuming that the nRT is all in parenthesis).  What is the general equation for $\Delta H$, since we are dealing here with a liquid and a solid?

Comment: Does the equation you wrote for $\Delta U$ when there is a change of phase?

Comment: @ChesterMiller I don't understand you.

Comment: I meant to say, does the equation you wrote **apply**...

Comment: @ChesterMiller so $\Delta U =nC_v\Delta T$ is only for expansion/contraction of gases?

Comment: For ideal gases, it describes much more than that.   But it doesn't describe $\Delta U$ for a change of phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are considering the $\Delta H$ and the $\Delta U$ between the following two thermodynamic equilibrium states:

**State 1:**  1 mole of ice at 0 C and 1 atm.

**State 2:**  1 mole of liquid water at 0 C and 1 atm.

The relationship between $\Delta H$ and $\Delta U$ at constant pressure is:
$$\Delta H=\Delta U + p\Delta V$$where V is molar volume.  What is the molar volume of ice?  What is the molar volume of liquid water?  What is $\Delta V$?

Comment: So ∆H and∆U will denote the heat change and internal energy change between two equilibrium states at constant pressure?

Comment: what is the equation to be applied for phase change?

Comment: @the.eleventh.letter I have no idea what you are asking.  Please elaborate.

Comment: The question asked here was how to find ∆u when ∆h is given. However you ended up ur answer with questions 'what is molar volume of ice, water?' so I didn't quite understand that.

Comment: Did u mean, we jave to subtract molar volume of ice and water.. to find ∆v?

Comment: @the eleventh letter Yes.  That is exactly what I mean.